# bad requests when creating guild sticker in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

Im new to discord.py and this is my first bot. I created a command to steal a sticker and adapted it to steal an image.

and got a `HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50046): Invalid Asset`

```
    if message.stickers:
      sticker = message.stickers[0]
      async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(sticker.url) as res:
          sticker_bytes = await res.read()
          file = discord.File(io.BytesIO(sticker_bytes),filename="sticker.png")
          await ctx.guild.create_sticker(name=sticker.name,
                                         description=" ",
                                         emoji=":skull:",
                                         file=file)
```

```
    elif message.attachments:
      sticker = message.attachments[0]
      async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(sticker.url) as res:
          sticker_bytes = await res.read()
          file = discord.File(io.BytesIO(sticker_bytes), filename=sticker.filename)
          await ctx.guild.create_sticker(name=sticker.filename,
                                         description=" ",
                                         emoji=":skull:",
                                         file=file)
```

the first code example takes input from a replied to message and turns it into a sticker. The second one is where the error is occurring